# Indesign: same color (gradient) looks differently on 2 pages

Tags: adobe-indesign

This InDesign document has 2 pages. On each page there is a rectangle that uses same gradient color. Looks differently:

[image]

What mystery should I attribute this phenomenon to?

Comment: It could be the preview. Are you on high display performance?

Comment: Positive. Positive.

Comment: It's very hard to say without seeing screenshots of each page with the object and color panel showing. My guess is one is RGB and the other is CMYK or something along those lines.

Comment: By definition "gradient" is more than one color. Your image shows the bottom of one rectangle and the top of another. Without seeing *complete* context it's difficult to say "why" these look different.

Comment: What I actually did is just going to the first page, drawing a rectangle, clicking on gradient swatch to assign fill color, and then repeat the same thing on the second page. So there is hardly a reason for different color modes / other swatches to be present. But seemingly in the exported file colors look the same, but it bothers me anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. According to [this](http://www.justskins.com/forums/indesign-doc-displays-color-72266.html) thread transparency blend mode should be changed to RGB.